# Question about environment variable in toolchain

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

I am trying to develop a toolchain for wllvm (whole program LLVM) on bazel 3.7 following the tutorial (link to the tutorial). A problem I have is I have to pass an environment variable (LLVM_COMPILER) to wllvm. Can you possibly provide more details here or a concrete example? Is it possible to directly configure the environment variable in `.bazelrc`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to set an environment variable for each Bazel action, then use `--action-env` flag

```py
# .bazelrc
build --action_env=LLVM_COMPILER=wllvm
```